# Why are there two tensions on my free body diagram?

Tags: forces

[image: Pulley Problem]

A man sits on a platform attached to a pulley and pulls himself up as shown (ignore the angle of the rope - it should be vertical). Apparently, the man/platform object has a force of 2T pulling it up. Why is it not just T?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When I scrolled down to read the question, the top of the picture got cut off. Then I just saw the platform/guy system held up by what looks like two different ropes. Certainly there is $2T$ then. Why would the answer change if these two ropes happen to be connected to each other somehow.

Comment: I'm pretty sure on the original diagram, he was only holding the right end of the rope. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What is the other end attached to then? Just the ground?

Comment: It's a pulley. Attaches to platform on the left, loops over the top and dangles. He grabs the dangling end and pulls himself up

Comment: Ok, I see. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. I should think of it as two ropes

Comment: If the man on the trapeze pulls himself up, the tension in the rope will only be half his weight.  But if he reaches the top, and ties off the rope he's pulling to a convenient hook (not on the trapeze!) the tension in the rope jumps to equal his weight. Neat trap, if the breaking strength is 0.75 his weight...